# Coloring rules for legend symbols

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering how I could have **one** of my **legend symbols (squares)** to be **colored according to**`adjustcolor("blue",alpha.f=0.05)`.

I'm trying the **below R code** (with no success):

```
curve(dt(x,19),-5,5)

legend("topright",legend=c(expression(paste("Power")),expression(paste(beta))),
density=c(15,0),angle=140,fill=T,col=c(adjustcolor("blue",alpha.f=0.05),0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and modify as necessary. I've made `alpha.f=.5` to make the color more distinct (`.05` is very low to perceive) and added `cex=1.5` to scale everything up to show colors clearer.

```
curve(dt(x,19),-5,5)

legend("topright",legend=c(expression(paste("Power")),expression(paste(beta))),
       ,fill=c(adjustcolor("blue",alpha.f=.5),"white"),density=c(NA,NA),angle=c(NA,NA), bg = NA, cex = 1.5)

legend("topright",legend=c(expression(paste("Power")),expression(paste(beta))),
       ,fill=c("black","white"),density=c(15,NA),angle=c(140,NA), bg = NA, cex =1.5)
```